# how to add an attribute from an object to a JScrollPane in java

Tags: java, jscrollpane

I have declared an ArrayList and DefaultListModel

```
DefaultListModel model;

List<AddFlight> Flights = new ArrayList<AddFlight>();
```

To this list I add an object as an element

```
Flights.add(new AddFlight(txtFlightNo.getText(),
            (String)cmbMechanicalStatus.getSelectedItem(),
            (String)cmbMedicalStatus.getSelectedItem(),
            Float.valueOf((txtFuelLevel.getText()).trim()).floatValue(),
            (String)cmbWeatherCondition.getSelectedItem(),
            (String)cmbFrequency.getSelectedItem()));
```

In the action Performed (ActionEvent e) I want to print **each object** in **one line** in a understandable way on the JScrollPane.

```
model.add(0,Flights);
```

My output looks like this [When I add **2 objects** to the ArrayList]:

[image]

WHAT I WANT:

**1)** I want each object in the ArrayList to appear in one line.

**2)** And I want it to appear like this in the JScrollPane:

---

Flight No: UL209, Mechanical Status:OK, Medical Status : Failure,Fuel Level : 12.0  ***//Line one***

Flight No: UL210, Mechanical Status:OK, Medical Status : OK,Fuel Level : 22.0  ***// Line two***

---

However, I managed to print out each element using the code below :

```
   for (AddFlight Flight : Flights) {
        System.out.println("FLight No : " + Flight.getFlightNo());
        System.out.println("Mechanical Status : " + Flight.getMechanicalStatus());
        System.out.println("Medical Status : " + Flight.getMedicalStatus());
        System.out.println("Fuel Level : " + Flight.getFuelLevel());
        System.out.println("Weather Condition: " + Flight.getWeatherCondition());
        System.out.println("Frequency : " + Flight.getFrequency());

    }
```

---

MY FULL CODE

---

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Flight implements ActionListener {

//String array
String[] MechanicalStatus = {"Select", "Ok", "Failure"};
String[] MedicalStatus = {"Select", "Ok", "Failure"};
String[] WeatherCondition = {"Select", "Sunny", "Raining", "Thunder", "Hurricane"};
String[] Frequency = {"Will be AutoSet", "ATC 1", "ATC 2", "ATC 3"};
//JPanel
JPanel pnlInput = new JPanel(new GridLayout(7, 2, 20, 20));
//Add textfields here
JTextField txtFlightNo = new JTextField(8);
JComboBox cmbMechanicalStatus = new JComboBox(MechanicalStatus);
JComboBox cmbMedicalStatus = new JComboBox(MedicalStatus);
JTextField txtFuelLevel = new JTextField(8);
JComboBox cmbWeatherCondition = new JComboBox(WeatherCondition);
JComboBox cmbFrequency = new JComboBox(Frequency);
//Add labels here
JLabel lblFlightNo = new JLabel("Flight No : ");
JLabel lblMechanicalStatus = new JLabel("Mechanical Status : ");
JLabel lblMedicalStatus = new JLabel("Medical Status : ");
JLabel lblFuelLevel = new JLabel("Fuel Level (gallons) : ");
JLabel lblWeatherCondition = new JLabel("Weather Condition :");
JLabel lblFrequency = new JLabel("Frequency : ");
List<AddFlight> Flights = new ArrayList<AddFlight>();
DefaultListModel model;

public Flight(DefaultListModel model) {

    this.model = model;

    //Adding flightno to panel
    pnlInput.add(lblFlightNo);
    pnlInput.add(txtFlightNo);

    //Adding mechanicalstatus to the panel
    pnlInput.add(lblMechanicalStatus);
    pnlInput.add(cmbMechanicalStatus);

    //Adding medicalstatus to the panel
    pnlInput.add(lblMedicalStatus);
    pnlInput.add(cmbMedicalStatus);

    //Adding fuellevel to the panel
    pnlInput.add(lblFuelLevel);
    pnlInput.add(txtFuelLevel);

    //Adding weathercondition to the panel
    pnlInput.add(lblWeatherCondition);
    pnlInput.add(cmbWeatherCondition);

    //Adding frequency to the panel
    pnlInput.add(lblFrequency);
    pnlInput.add(cmbFrequency);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, pnlInput, "Flight Details",
            JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

    if (result == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
        System.out.println("Plane [" + txtFlightNo.getText() + "] has arrived at the airport.\n");
        System.out.println("Mechanical status " + cmbMechanicalStatus.getSelectedItem() + "\n");
    }



    Flights.add(new AddFlight(txtFlightNo.getText(),
            (String) cmbMechanicalStatus.getSelectedItem(),
            (String) cmbMedicalStatus.getSelectedItem(),
            Float.valueOf((txtFuelLevel.getText()).trim()).floatValue(),
            (String) cmbWeatherCondition.getSelectedItem(),
            (String) cmbFrequency.getSelectedItem()));

    //persons.add(new AddFlight("UL210", "FAILURE", "OK", 90, "Rainy", "ATC 2"));


    for (AddFlight Flight : Flights) {
        System.out.println("FLight No : " + Flight.getFlightNo());
        System.out.println("Mechanical Status : " + Flight.getMechanicalStatus());
        System.out.println("Medical Status : " + Flight.getMedicalStatus());
        System.out.println("Fuel Level : " + Flight.getFuelLevel());
        System.out.println("Weather Condition: " + Flight.getWeatherCondition());
        System.out.println("Frequency : " + Flight.getFrequency());

    }

    model.add(0, Flights);
}
}
```

---

Any Help is appreciated...

Comment: A better way would be writing your own ListModelAdapter (implementing ListModel): you already have the list you want to show - the Flights variable holds it. You only need the adapter to convert your representation of the data (List<AddFlight>) to the one JList accepts. That way you don't need to synchronize your list to the JList model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're displaying your list twice in your control. Additionally, if you want to display relevant information rather than simply the object type and memory address, you need to define a `toString` method:

```
public String toString()
{
    return "Flight No: " + flightNo + ", Mechanical Status:" + mechStatus + ", Medical Status : " + medStatus + ",Fuel Level : " + fuel;
}
```

EDIT:

It looks like, in order to display each `AddFlight` object on one line, you should be using

```
model.add(0, Flights.get(Flights.size() - 1));
```

(Add each `AddFlight` object to your model individually)

Instead of

```
model.add(0,Flights);
```

(Adding the entire `ArrayList` to your model each time you add a new element)

Comment: let me check this, after im dressed up. I think this would work. gimme 5 mins